# Django LDAP Active Directory Authentification

Tags: django, authentication, active-directory, ldap

Im trying to adjust my django project to connect to AD.
Using libraries django-auth-ldap, ldap.
Binding user is fine, creating and populating django user - ok.
But in the end, authentification fails with next output:

```
Binding as CN=bind,CN=Users,DC=ATK,DC=BIZ
Invoking search_s('DC=ATK,DC=BIZ', 2, '(sAMAccountName=admin)')
search_s('DC=ATK,DC=BIZ', 2, '(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)') returned 1 objects: cn=admin,cn=users,dc=atk,dc=biz
Binding as cn=admin,cn=users,dc=atk,dc=biz
Binding as CN=bind,CN=Users,DC=ATK,DC=BIZ
cn=admin,cn=users,dc=atk,dc=biz is a member of cn=django-admins,cn=users,dc=atk,dc=biz
Creating Django user admin
Populating Django user admin
Caught LDAPError while authenticating admin: OPERATIONS_ERROR({'msgtype': 111, 'msgid': 6, 'result': 1, 'desc': 'Operations error', 'ctrls': [], 'info': '000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-031007E5, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0\n'})
```

My settings.py file is below:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
]
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://BORUM.ATK.BIZ"
AUTH_LDAP_BASE_DN = "DC=ATK,DC=BIZ"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "CN=bind,CN=Users,DC=ATK,DC=BIZ"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "***"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(
            AUTH_LDAP_BASE_DN,
            ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
            "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)"
            )

# AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = "cn=%(user)s,cn=users,dc=ATK,dc=BIZ"

AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = {
    ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL: 255,
    ldap.OPT_REFERRALS: 0,
}

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "username": "sAMAccountName",
    "first_name": "givenName",
    # "last_name": "sn",
}

AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(
    "DC=ATK,DC=BIZ",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    "(objectCategory=group)",
)
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType(name_attr="cn")
AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP = "CN=django-admins,CN=Users,DC=ATK,DC=BIZ"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_superuser": "CN=django-admins,CN=Users,CN=ATK,CN=BIZ",
    "is_staff": "CN=django-admins,CN=Users,DC=ATK,DC=BIZ",
}


AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True
AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_GROUPS = True
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600
```

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Error number 000020D6 indicates that ERROR_DS_CANT_ACCESS_REMOTE_PART_OF_AD, I dont really understand how to treat that error, how binding and getting data of user is successful, but have no access to a remote part of AD.